# Why is the route not executed in the following code?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to make the server `console log` any fetch that it receives in the third `app.use` but this makes the routes after it not executed. Why? Is this not the ideal way for doing general response on any request?..

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const bbdb = require('./database/bbDB');
const sql = require('./database/sql');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); //keep this to true to be able to post nested object
app.use((json)=>{
  console.log('receiving fetch at: ' + json.originalUrl);
});

app.get('/api/hello', (req, res) => {
  res.send({express: 'Hello'});
});

app.get('/api/hello/data', async (req, res) =>{
    try{
      console.log('receiving fetch at: ' + req.originalUrl);
      const reqQuery = req.query;
      let results = await bbdb.queryProducts(sql.all_home_desc);
      res.send(results);
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    } 
});


app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the next middleware manually. Try the following:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`receiving fetch at: ${req.url}`);
  next();
});
```

Comment: It works now. Thanks. Another weird behaviour that i get from this is now that whenever it receives a new http request, it always `log` the same `req.originalUrl` from the first request. Any idea why?

Comment: For that I'm not sure to be honest, try assembling the full URL using:
`var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;`

Answer (score 0):

As vitor said, your middleware needs to call `next()`, this calls the next function in your server's stack, either the next middleware in order or the function that handles the request.

This is so that you can optionally stop the request from passing through, like for authentication middleware, if someone requests a delete, if the auth middle finds out he's not allowed, it shouldn't call next.